# enable i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 in fedora

Tags: fedora, intel, intel-graphics, i915

I have a intel skylake cpu and I read this article in Phoronix http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=intel-skl-prelim-support, claiming some issues are present at this moment and the solution to these is enable `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1`.

So the question is how to do it in fedora 22 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just battled this problem yesterday and had the same question.  Basically, you need to add the i915.preliminary... text to the command line that loads the kernel.

1. When booting, and the Grub screen is displayed with the default Fedora version displayed, the instructions at the bottom of the screen say that you can press 'e' to bring up the editor.  Do it.  In the editor move the cursor all the way to the bottom, so you are typing a fresh line, and type in the i915.preliminary...... text.  Press Ctrl-X to continue booting with the new parameter.

Assuming it works for you, you will want to make it permanent.

2. Install grub-customizer which is a graphical GRUB2 settings manager.  You can enter the i915.preliminary.... text in the appropriate box of the 'General' tab and then save the modified file(s).